# How to remove strange logo during startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, malware-removal

**Problem**

- During startup, My system shows an extra logo before the default Windows 10 logo. How to remove it?
- Is my system infected with malware?

[image]

**Details**

- This logo is just come out of nowhere. I haven't tried or did anything to change startup logo.
- It is KKU university logo that is not related to Laptop's OEM(Lenovo) or Windows 10. I remember that I've downloaded a PDF file from KKU university website but I think it is not possible for PDF file to change startup logo on my system.
- My laptop(Lenovo V14-ARE) is personal not from company/organization. I've installed genuine Windows 10 by myself.

**What I've tried and research**

- Run quick scan from Windows Defender Antivirus and also Malwarebytes. Nothing found.
- I've found that many people use software named [HackBGRT](https://github.com/Metabolix/HackBGRT) to change startup logo but I think it can not apply here because,
  first, I'm not try to change default Windows 10 to something else. I just want to remove an unexpected extra logo.
  Second, My laptop does not support UEFI which is required to use HackBGRT.

Comment: I can't comment, but I have a few questions. - Is your laptop part of the KKU University domain / organization? - Was the laptop previously owned by someone part of the KKU domain / organization?
- Other than that one PDF file you mentioned, does your laptop have any relation to this organization? If the answer to all of these questions is "No", can you try running a rootkit scan using [Kaspersky's TDSSKiller](https://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/tdsskiller)?

Comment: No, My laptop is personal and first-handed. I tried TDSSKiller nothing found but I've managed to fixed it before I ran that software by flashing BIOS. I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by flashing BIOS. Default Lenovo logo is back now.